# How to split a string on delimiter and append a constant value to all elements

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file with each line in below format

```
KeyA=ValA1,ValA2,ValA3...ValAn 
KeyB=ValB1,ValB2,ValB3....ValBn
```

I have multiples lines in that file with varying number of values for each line.

My task is to append `Val Key` for each line. Expected sample output:

```
ValA1 KeyA
ValA2 KeyA
ValA3 KeyA
ValB1 KeyB
ValB2 KeyB
ValB3 KeyB
```

What I tried is :

```
while read -r line; do
    KEY=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 1)
    VALUES=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 2)
    for VAL in $VALUES;do
        echo $VAL $KEY
    done
done < file.txt
```

I am able to achieve the expected output, but I am supposed to complete this without using the `for` loop. 
Can someone suggest me any other solution.

Comment: Are you sure it works? Because `VALUES` still has commas in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should not parse line-based text files with shell loops; shell is interpreted one line at a time as a program is read. This is extremely inefficient for bulk jobs. Please use dedicated text processors like awk or perl.

```
awk -F'[=,]' '{k=$1; for(f=2;f<=NF;f++) print $f, k}' file
```

- `-F'[=,]'` - Fields are delimited by a single comma/equals
- `{...}` - with no condition, this action will be performed on every line
- `k=$1` - set `k` to Field 1
- `for(f=2;f<=NF;f++)` - iterate over all remaining fields (NF = Number of Fields)
- `print $f, k` - print the field, a space, and the value of `k`

Comment: Thanks, I dont know that awk can split multiple delimiters.

Comment: @Abhinay Any valid regex can be used as Field Separator; it's awesome. GNU Awk can do the same for the Record Separator (newline by default).

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution. First substitute `=` and `,` for a space. Then read each line with xargs and execute a script, that will buffer the first argument (ie. they key) and output with iterating over all the others:

```
<inputfile tr '[=,]' ' ' |
xargs -l  sh -c 't="$1"; shift; printf "$t %s\n" "$@"' --
```

On my second try I did the following, where I don't substitute `=` for a space, so if values have `=` in them, it doesn't get's split up.

```
while IFS== read -r key vals; do
  printf "%s" "$vals" |
  xargs -d, printf "$key %s\n"
done <inputfile
```